# C3P0 apparent deadlock warning relation to row lock contention in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, c3p0

I'm getting a lot of apparent deadlock warnings in a multithreaded application.
The causes are already discussed in many threads, for example here:
[APPARENT DEADLOCK c3p0 0.9.5.1 spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952887/apparent-deadlock-c3p0-0-9-5-1-spring)

I experienced almost in the same time row lock contention events in the connecting Oracle database. There were some UPDATE statements which were blocked on row locks.
Now my question is: can it be a connection between the c3p0 warning and the Oracle row locks, and if yes, what is this connection between the two? Eliminating the c3p0 problem would also eliminate the Oracle row lock problem?
(edit: it's hard to reproduce the problem locally, so I have to stay unfortunately on the theoretical side)